# Recovering Windows Files Through Ubuntu

Tags: windows, data-recovery

I am using Ubuntu after my windows 7 has crashed. Can I recover all of my files by navigating to the "Windows 7 OS" tab under devices and just moving everything over to the external? Which folders and files am I looking to move to get all of them? Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. You might want to have a look at our [help] or take the [tour]. Next time, _try_ copying things over and post here if you encounter problems. Now, what do you mean by "all of them"? How do you expect us to know where _you_ keep your files?

Answer (score 0):

I will suppose you didn't overwrite your Windows installation to install Ubuntu. If that's the case I have some bad news for you. Other than that, which files you want is irrelevant. Check out [This](http://www.wikihow.com/Access-Windows-Files-in-Ubuntu) link which uses gparted to access your windows partitions :)

And to answer your question: Yes, whichever file you move to your external drive will be available.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Dear Danatela, forfive my answer's simplicity. It is, in fact, the first answer I give on askubuntu. However, I suppose our friend here is smart enough to open a link in a new tab and follow a set of instructions presented by a more experienced person than me. If you want to copy another webpage just for the sake of copying, be my guest. I prefer to consider people here smart enough to open a new link and follow 8 steps.

Comment: This has nothing to do with asker's smartness, it has relevance for the fact that links become obsolete, their content may change significantly and answer you want asker to follow may just disappear.

Comment: 1) I implied nothing for the asker's smartness.
2) I suppose a WikiHow link will not change before the asker gets the information he needs.
3) I cannot include an 8 steps guide with pictures in a 500 chars answer.
4) Even if the webpage changes the asker can indicate the change and I will be more than happy to guide him myself to do what he wants to.

100% of the time people ask me something I send a link to them and they get it done. I thought the purpose of this forum was to solve problems here and now, not create an online tutorial. If that's the case my bad for thinking I can help.